# Z3: how to Extract() from a constant number?

Tags: python, z3

In Z3 Python, to extract 8 bits of a BitVector V, we can do as following:

```
Extract(7, 0, V)
```

However, sometimes in my program, V can be a constant, so in that case the code is literally like:

```
Extract(7, 0, 0x87654)
```

This is unfortunately wrong, as above code does not specify that 0x87654 is a 32-bit BitVector.7

One solution is to create a temporary variable, something like:

```
tmp = BitVec('tmp', 32)
tmp == 0x87654
Extract(7, 0, tmp)
```

However, this is a bit troublesome, as I have to create a temporary for this to work. I am wondering if there is another way without having to create a temporary variable? Is there any way to cast 0x87654 into BitVector inline in my code?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to use `BitVecVal(value, bits)`:

```
Extract(7, 0, BitVecVal(0x87654, 32))
```

Here's the API description: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/z3.html#-BitVecVal